Does any tetrahedron have a billiard orbit touching each face once?
For a triangle, a similar construction (a billiard orbit touching each edge once) is called the Fagnano orbit. It is well known and easy to construct, but there is very little information for tetrahedra.
This orbit is constructed for a regular tetrahedron (as shown in the Wolfram Demonstration Conway's Billiard Ball Loop), but how can it be geometrically constructed for an arbitrary tetrahedron and does it always exist?

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455160/is-there-an-inventory-of-closed-billiard-paths-in-a-regular-tetrahedron

Related: https://hal.science/hal-01219098v1/document They show that for a tetrahedron with three right angles concurring at a vertex, a Fagnano orbit doesn't exist.

Partial result:

A tetrahedron whose faces are congruent isosceles triangles has a "billiard loop".


If each isosceles face of $OABC$ has base $s$ and legs $t$, define points on faces using barycentric coordinates of vertices:
$$\begin{align}
O' = \frac{p A + q(B + C)}{p + 2q} &\qquad
A' = \frac{p O + q(B + C)}{p + 2q} \\[4pt]
B' = \frac{p C + q(A + O)}{p + 2q} &\qquad
C' = \frac{p B + q(A + O)}{p + 2q}
\end{align}$$
where $$p:q \;=\; 4 \left(2t^2-s^2\right):\left(4t^2-s^2\right)$$

To demonstrate that this works, define $h:=\sqrt{\frac12(2t^2-s^2)}$ (the distance between the midpoints of $OA$ and $BC$), and coordinatize thusly:
$$
O = \left(-m,0,n\right) \quad 
A = \left(m,0,n\right) \quad 
B = \left(0,-m,-n\right) \quad
C = \left(0,m,-n\right)$$
$$m := \tfrac12s \qquad n :=\tfrac12h$$
Here, $|OA|=|BC|=s$ and $|OB|=|BA|=|AC|=|CO|=t$. We can then calculate
$$O' = \left(m', 0, -n'\right) \quad
A' = \left(-m', 0, -n'\right) \quad
B' = \left(0, m', n'\right) \quad
C' = \left(0, -m', n'\right)$$
$$m' := \frac{2 h^2 s}{8 h^2 + s^2} \qquad
n' := \frac{h s^2}{2 (8 h^2 + s^2)}$$
One readily checks that the altitude of (isosceles) $\triangle O'B'C'$ through $O'$ (ie, the line through $O'$ and the midpoint of $B'C'$) aligns with vector $(2 h, 0, -s)$, which is normal to $\triangle ABC$. This confirms that the path $B'\to O'\to C'$ reflects off of face $ABC$. Likewise for $O'\to C'\to A'$, $C'\to A'\to B'$, and $A'\to B'\to O'$, giving a complete billiard loop. $\square$

Note: In a regular tetrahedron, $s=t$ and $p:q=4:3$. Writing  $K:=\frac13(A+B+C)$ for the centroid of $\triangle ABC$, we find
$$O'-K \;=\; \tfrac1{30}(2 A - B - C) \;=\; \tfrac1{10}(A-K)$$
Thus, $O'$ is the dilation of $A$ in $K$ by scale factor $1/10$; likewise with $A'$, $B'$, $C'$. This agrees with the description of the referenced Wolfram Demonstration Conway's Billiard Ball Loop, which indicates that each vertex of the loop is also a vertex of triangle one-tenth the size of each face (specifically, the dilation of the face in its centroid, with scale factor $1/10$).
